# Weblogic console 11g Data derivation

Tags: weblogic11g

We all see our Weblogic console (11g) and it gives a certain amount of information to us, but I was wondering where this weblogic console derives the data from, from a database or from the domain we made?

Comment: Can you give an example of the 'information' you are talking about ?

Comment: I'm talking about the things for example currently open sockets count , server health . 

In simple words our console is GUI but where is the data on that GUI is coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you speak about general information like what is deployed, what is the status of...

Weblogic do not use a database. Data come from configuration file (static data) or from JMX (runtime value).

Note that you can also enable SNMP on the admin. Admin gather data from node, and is able to push / give data through SNMP.